# final specifier has no effect with separate declaration and definition

Tags: c++, c++11, final, virtual-functions

I noticed some strange behaviour with `final` keyword. When I do:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void foo() final {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() override {}
};
```

I get compiler error on overriding `foo` in `B` as I would expect. But when I make separate definition and declaration of A::foo

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void foo() final;
};

void A::foo() {}

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() override {}
};
```

the error is gone. Is it as it should be or a compiler bug?

//edit: gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1)

Comment: Why don't you check release notes? These are old versions of g++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I believe this is the answer. If you post I'll upvote!

Comment: Is there a `B` in the second snippet, too?

Comment: @ÖöTiib It’s the latest stable version I can get on Debian 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both snippets should generate a compiler error about overiding a `final` function. This seems like a compiler bug. [gcc 4.9.2](https://godbolt.org/g/h4nR9q) compiles and [gcc 4.9.3](https://godbolt.org/g/sXDt4E) generates an error.

Comment: I assumed it is obvious that B belongs to the second snippet as well.

Comment: @PKua It may seem obvious, but the question was raised in the comments. It also took me a couple of read-through to deduce that `B` was assumed to be part of the 2nd snippet. I clearly state the assumption that it was to avoid any confusion.